# How can I get the web page size programmatically?

Tags: javascript, php, page-size

Is there a way to get web page size using php or javascript ?
I want to do this for 100s of domain.

Edit 
I am not sure what it means
[image]
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean web page size? A Web page does not normally have a size, it's sized to the browser window which can change.

Comment: Do you mean webpage size like file size or window size?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions @ volter9 & Zipper
I have edited the question what i mean!

Comment: no, you can't get the full size info like that from JS. you can find some of the total weight contributions, but not nearly all of them.

Comment: I want to compare the web page every month to check if there were any changes in the layout. To do so I thought of getting the download size!

Comment: @Penny see my answer use: `get_headers`

Answer (score 1):

if you don't need the page don't use `file_get_contents()` you transfer the whole file for nothing.

instead use

```
get_headers ( string $url [, int $format = 0 ] )
```

then just extract the **Content-Length**

UPDATE- for checking if its changed use the above then compare **Last-Modified**

Comment: This will give only header content length right?

Comment: What if there are changes in body? It will not change the length in that case?

Comment: **** Last-Modified******

Comment: Thanks. But in some domains I am not getting `Last-modified` index. Foe example- in case of domain https://www.ecommercewebsites.com.au/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `file_get_contents()` and then simply read the byte size of the result. There are also online tools which you can make a use of their APIs.

Also note, file_get_content() will simply get the content of the webpage as string, that is being said, if you are wanting to get the size including images and etc then you can use something like http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php